# Had to reset password to login, but now Icloud will not accept new password

Tags: macos, passwords, keychain

After not using my MAC laptop for quite some time, I decided to fire it up, only to discover i forgot my password. After numerous attempts I was offered by OSX to reset the password, with some mention of keychain. I originally decided to keep the original keychain, but after dozens of pop up windows relentless started to pollute my screen, I logged off and logged in again using 'create new keychain'. I thought this would be the end of this, but a persistent Icloud window is now popping up.

When I tried entering the new password, a dialogue window came up about creating **ANOTHER NEW PASSWORD** .Unsure of what to do , I simply closed the dialogue box and tried entering my newly created password (thinking I might have mistyped it several times). Now I am not offered any options, other than a recurring, and self-replicating Icloud window which is asking for my password that will not go away.

After logging out and back in again, another message appears "OSX wants to use the 'Local Items' Keychain. When I enter my new password it is rejected.

Perhaps I am unaware, but is my Icloud password the same as my AppleID password? I wish this was a a simpler process but it seems very complicated and without any instruction on how to proceed. How can I log back into my machine and fix the keychain so I don't have to deal with all these broken links?

**EDIT 1 -** now it says " A keychain cannot be found to store "registrationV1"The there is an option to restore to defaults, which then warns me will delete all my passwords.

(what is registrationV1 anyways)? Why would OSX nuke my keychain if I was able to create a new login with secure credentials as the owner of this computer?

**EDIT 2 -** S0 I decided to just reset the keychain, but as soon as I finish completing this step, another dialogue box appears:
"Messages Agent wants to use the "Local Items" keychain. then prompts for password. Again, the newly created password is rejected.

So at this point I am not even able to create a new keychain, as it accepts my password, then shows me another windows about a Messenger which doesn't accept my password, and then it is apparent that the keychain isn't reset again as it asks me to reset again, despite that I already did. **Endless cycle of lameness.**

I have a big music gig next week and need to get this sorted promptly, so any help is appreciated.

Running OSX 10.9.5 on Macbook pro.

Comment: Ultimately, this is an Apple account issue.

Comment: @music2myear perhaps it is but it’s made my machine unusable now as iCloud is toast now. It won’t even open anymore. I’m not sure how to adresss any keychain issues without being able to access iCloud. What a nightmare!

Comment: Your local computer credentials are not in any way related to your Apple ID, so you have two separate issues - 1) you've blown away the local keychain association by brute-forcing your way in & 2) you're on an OS that cannot use 2FA, which Apple now insist on. I think El Capitan is the oldest OS that can still get that to work. How to proceed next may be dependant on how easy it's going to be to reinstall older apps you still rely on. If you can reinstall easily & have good backups, I'd nuke & pave to El Cap.